# Creating empty array in class of JavaScript giving syntax error

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two files in the same directory as `06classjs.js` and 07 `classObjects.js`

`06classjs.js`

```
class User {
  constructor(name, email) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
  }
  courseList = [];

  getInfo() {
    return { name: this.name, email: this.email };
  }
  enrollCourse(name) {
    this.courseList.push(name);
  }
  getCourseList() {
    return this.courseList;
  }
}

module.exports = User;
```

`07 classObjects.js`

```
const User = require("./06classjs.js");

const dilip = new User("Dilip", "dilip@gmail.com");

console.log(dilip.getInfo());

dilip.enrollCourse("React");
```

When I am trying to run 07 classObjects.js using node it gives a syntax error for array declaration.

Error log

```
courseList = [];
             ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/media/dilip/4E622DC7622DB49D/Courses/LCO/JSTube/06 Advanceish/07 classObjects.js:3:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Why isn't `courseList = [];` in your constructor as `this.courseList: = [];`?

Comment: Is that supposed to be a variable shared by all class instances? You need to write `static courseList = [];`

Comment: But you can't access static variables with `this`, it should be `User.courseList`.

Comment: tried but not working @Barmar

Comment: Static class variables are only supported by newest browser versions.

Comment: For the record, chrome's supported static class fields since m72; i.e. January 2019. So if you're using/developing for chrome, it should be fine. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields#browser_compatibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be running an outdated version of node.js.

Support for public instance class fields was [added in version 12.4.0](https://node.green/#ES2022-features-instance-class-fields-public-instance-class-fields).